# Pytest: how to work around missing __init__.py in the tests folder?

Tags: python, pytest

I am storing all the pytest files in the `tests` sub-directory under the project root. There is no `__init__.py` in that directory or above and `pytest tests/test_a.py` works as expected. I can also run `pytest test_a.py` directly from within the `tests` folder.

```
|--<project_root>
+---[tests]
    test_a.py
    base.py
    config.py
    conftest.py
```

The test class in `test_a.py` inherits from `base.py`. Now, the problem is that because of the missing `__init__.py` the IDE tooling does not work and the imports cannot be resolved. Adding `__init__.py` under the `tests` resolves all import errors in the IDE, but tests won't run anymore with `pytest test_a.py` because py.test fails to import `conftest.py`.

In my `conftest.py` I have the following imports:

```
from config import HOST_URL_DEFAULT, USER, PASSWORD
```

which results in:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
ERROR: could not load /project_root/tests/conftest.py
```

Is there a way to solve this so that both IDE tooling works *and* `pytest` keeps working? I would like to avoid using dot imports, if possible.

<sup>*Update:* After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/191246) I think I am finally starting to understand a bit more how python imports work.</sup>

Comment: Why does ``pytest`` fail to import ``config.py``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: it was `conftest.py` that pytest cannot import, sorry for the typo. I am not explicitly importing `conftest.py` anywhere in my test code, but the file is present and I am using it. I updated the question to show what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: So the issue is rather with your IDE than with `pytest`? Maybe it's possible to tell the IDE that `tests` is a namespace package somewhere in the project settings. If you place `__init__.py` in the `tests` dir, the qualified name of `config` module will change to `tests.config` and you have to adapt the imports as the answer suggests. One way or the other, it may be worth checking out [Good Integration Practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code) for hints on different test layouts.

Comment: At least in PyCharm, you can add `tests` as source root in the project settings; this resolves the import issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `__init__.py` and use a relative or absolute import in `conftest.py`:

```
# relative
from .config import HOST_URL_DEFAULT, USER, PASSWORD
# absolute
from tests.config import HOST_URL_DEFAULT, USER, PASSWORD
```

In a package (identified by `__init__.py`), you need unambiguous import paths. Using unqualified imports (`from config import ...`) depends on `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.modules` including your package root - this is generally not robust and should be avoided as it circumvents the package infrastructure.

What you have here (`config.py` used by other modules) *is* a package. Treat it as one.

---

`pytest` does *not* discourage the use of a test package with an `__init__.py`! There are veritable use cases for this - such as yours.

What `pytest` [does discourage](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code) is having a source package *and* test package in the same source root. However, that means you should *move your source package*, not your test package!

```
mysource/  # root directory for both mypackage and mytests
+- mypackage/  # should be src/mypackage instead!
   +- __init__.py
   +- abcd.py
+- mytests
   +- __init__.py
   +- tests_abcd.py  # ``from mypackage import abcd`` imports from source
```

The problem is that running `mytests` means that `mypackage` is importable from source as well. That is, your tests are working on your *source package*, not your installed package. If there are any errors in your installation procedure, testing will not catch it. [See the blog linked in the `pytest` docs for details](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure).

Comment: My understanding was that `pytest` discourages the use of `__init__.py` for the tests, which does somehow manage to run the code without turning everything into a package.

Comment: ``pytest`` does not require you to turn non-packages into packages. You *already have* a package there, though.

Comment: @ccpizza I have added some further description that ``pytest`` discourage *having a source package next to* a test package, not having a test package per se.