# Python test file structure for GitHub actions

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-actions

I have the following directory structure:

```
main_dir/
    |--.git/
    |--.github/
        |--workflows/
            |--main.yml
    |--package/
        |--__init__.py
        |--config.py
    |--tests/
        |--pytest.ini
        |--test_config.py
```

And in `test/test_config.py` the first line import a class from the config.py file:

```
from package.config import Config
```

These test work when running locally, but on  GitHub Actions I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'`. The working directory is the same on both (main_dir). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: *How* do you run this file? Do you locally run it via some IDE perhaps, and as ``python test/test_config.py`` on GH Actions?

Comment: Locally, I use pycharm with the configuration options `target` and `Working Directory` set to the `main_dir`. On GH Actions I have `pipenv run pytest`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytest: how to work around missing __init__.py in the tests folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796370/pytest-how-to-work-around-missing-init-py-in-the-tests-folder)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That's done the trick! Adding the `__init__.py` has worked, though I was also under the impression that it shouldn't be there. Thanks for the answer and the resources, definitely have some reading up to do!

Answer (score -1):

Your IDE should add your project to your python path.

You can add this in your script using the following snippet:

```
import os
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
working_dir = os.path.join(current_dir , "..")

import sys
sys.path.append(working_dir)
```

You can now have your working directory in your python path using

```
from package.config import Config
```

To know what is present in your python path, just print `sys.path`.

The best practice is directly to add to your path the working directory.

- [On windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows)
- [On Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)
- [On MAC](https://gist.github.com/nex3/c395b2f8fd4b02068be37c961301caa7)