# Do __init__.py files in a child directory trigger __init__.py files in the parent directory? (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Python project is currently suffering from issues where my dependencies have conflicts. I wanted to solve that later, after I finished writing tests for a specific function in my code (`function_a.py` in `file_a.py`).

When I run pytest explicitly on the test file in this directory (`pytest test_a.py`) everything is fine and my tests pass. But if I add an `__init__.py` file to this directory my code errors due to the conflict between the dependencies (which are imported in the `__init__.py` file of the parent directory).

Works:

```
- parent_directory
 - other_files.py
 - __init__.py
 - child_directory
  - file_a.py
  - test_a.py
```

Does not work:

```
- parent_directory
 - other_files.py
 - __init__.py
 - child_directory
  - file_a.py
  - test_a.py
  - __init__.py
```

Why does the `__init__.py` in the child_directory causes my other `__init__.py` in the parent_directory to be executed?

Comment: `__init__.py` files (I'll update the post)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytest: how to work around missing ``__init__.py`` in the tests folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796370/pytest-how-to-work-around-missing-init-py-in-the-tests-folder)

Comment: Not really. My main question is less to do with pytest, and more to do with why is having a `__init__.py` in my child directory causing the` __init__.py` in my parent directory to be called?  Is it because the child_dir is a submodule to the parent_dir when `__init__.py` is present? And when a submodule is loaded, the module (parent) gets loaded too?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what *pytest* is doing as part of its automatic test execution.

Comment: Ah okay, starting to understand this now! So if i was just running `test_a.py` as a python file (`python test_a.py`) I would not be experiencing this issue?